# Normalize a unicode string in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, normalize

In PHP,

```
mb_strtolower('İspanyolca');
```

returns

```
U+0069  i  LATIN SMALL LETTER I
U+0307  ̇   COMBINING DOT ABOVE
U+0073  s  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
U+0070  p  LATIN SMALL LETTER P
etc.
```

I need to get rid of the "**U+0307  ̇   COMBINING DOT ABOVE**";

I tried this:

```
$TheUrl=mb_strtolower('İspanyolca');
$TheUrl=normalizer_normalize($TheUrl,Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

The **combining dot above** persists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't get normalized because even though there is no "latin small letter i with dot above" codepoint, but the combining mark is still potentially important if it ever gets translated back to uppercase. I would recommend leaving it as-is, but if it poses a demonstrable problem for you then you could add an explicit filter for replacing `i\u0307` with just `i`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086824/why-do-latin-small-letter-dotless-i-combining-dot-above-not-get-normalized-to this is not a bug in PHP, intl, or even i18n. This is a decision made by the unicode consortium at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this case, you can use the `strtr` function to replace specific characters in the string like my example below

```
$TheUrl = 'İspanyolca';
$TheUrl = mb_strtolower($TheUrl, 'UTF-8');
$TheUrl = strtr($TheUrl, array('i̇' => 'i', 'İ' => 'i'));
```

This will replace the lowercase `'i'` with a dot above and the uppercase `'İ'` with a regular lowercase `'i'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom function in PHP that performs Unicode normalization and then remove characters that are not part of the basic Latin alphabet.
So for example -

```
function removeDiacritics($str) {
    $normalizedStr = Normalizer::normalize($str, Normalizer::FORM_C);
    
    $cleanStr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $normalizedStr);
    return $cleanStr;
}

$TheUrl = mb_strtolower('İspanyolca');
$TheUrl = removeDiacritics($TheUrl);
echo $TheUrl;
```

Comment: Adi, why do I need the normalizer in the above code?  Why not just preg:replace without the normalizer?

Comment: @Cymro so unicode text can represent characters in multiple ways. Using normalize before pre_replace helps normalize which in turn helps handling various diacritics and accented characters correctly.

Comment: This doesn't remove diacritics, it removes literally everything other than then latin alphabet.

Comment: If you want to reduce a string to a 7-bit-safe "ASCII" representation, then there's [Transliterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator), but I don't think that this is necessarily what OP is after either.

Comment: @Sammitch i didn't get you by what you meant remove literally everything? I ran this code and got the output as `ispanyolca`

Comment: Try adding numbers or punctuation, maybe some slashes. eg: https://3v4l.org/SgF6m

Comment: Oh in that sense, i kept a generic example to just return a clean string